# Cutting a column into quantiles based on categories on another column using Python

Tags: python, data-science

In the titanic dataset I want to cut the Ticket Fare column into quantiles based on each embarked station with values C,S and Q.

For eg:

```
pd.qcut(titanic_train['Fare'],q=3,labels=['Low','Med','High'])
```

will cut the Fare column into quantiles irrespective of Embarked station which may not be true in case a customer has embarked from a different station.

Expected Sol: I would want a function to cut Fare column into 3 quantiles for each embarked station separately.

[image: Titanic dataset]

Comment: Post a sample of your dataset. Just mentioning "titanic dataset" is not enough.

Comment: have you tried `groupby` then `qcut`

Comment: @not_speshal - Have added a screenshot.

Comment: @Chris - I am unable to put it down in code.

Comment: Titanic dataset -- https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data?select=test.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to first use `pandas.groupby` and then `transform` with a `qcut` like so:

```
df["Quantile"] = df.groupby("Embarked")["Fare"].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 3, labels=['Low','Med','High']))

>>> df.head()
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass  ... Cabin Embarked  Quantile
0            1         0       3  ...   NaN        S       Low
1            2         1       1  ...   C85        C      High
2            3         1       3  ...   NaN        S       Low
3            4         1       1  ...  C123        S      High
4            5         0       3  ...   NaN        S       Low
```